# Order posts by date or keyword

Tags: search, wordpress

I want to enable website visitors to order WordPress posts on the category page by date posted or by search keyword, similarly to how it's done on this page:

http://www.steinwaymusical.com/news.php

I'd appreciate a plugin recommendation or any other suggestion from knowledgeable people.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has order and orderby options you can use in the query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

```
<?php 
$args = array('order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'name'); 
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
// echo out the title, excerpt
endwhile; 
?>
```

Your example page uses GET variables.

?selSort=name_asc&txtKeyword=sdfsdf

So you need to create a form with method="GET" that submit GET data to the current page. Then, using PHP, you can check if any GET data is set (in this case, selSort and txtKeyword). If either of those are set, put them into your query. Then you can modify the query to resemble this:

```
 <?php 
    $args = array('order' => $_GET['selSort'], 'orderby' => $_GET['txtKeyword']); 
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
    // echo out the title, excerpt
    endwhile; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ankur – this looks like what I've been trying to find! Could you please explain to me, what's the best way to implement such options with the date-and-keyword search form inserted in the page, like it's done in the example from my question?

Comment: The order and orderby can both come from $_GET. See the edit for more info.

Comment: Thank you, @Ankur, this is most helpful.